# Is there a way to return response body in Playwright?

Tags: python, playwright

I'm working with [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/python/). I would like to get response body (HTML) from network events instead of waiting for DOM to load data in browser, and then parse the elements. Current workflow looks something like that:

1. Playwright opens headless chromium
2. Opens first page with captcha (no data)
3. Solves captcha and redirects to the page with data

Sometimes a lot of data is returned and page takes quite a while to load in the browser, but all the data is already received from the client side in network events. My question is it possible to get network events in Playwright instead of waiting for all the elements to load.

I found [Network Events](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/network#handle-requests) documentation, and was able to get the HTML, but it returns all the requests instead of single request.

I'm using Playwright simply for navigation, form submitting, and to get website HTML.

Answer (score 5):

Just use some condition instead of print method, for example you could check if response contains some key in its json:

```
def run(playwright):
    chromium = playwright.chromium
    browser = chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    # Subscribe to "request" and "response" events.
    page.on("request", lambda request: print(">>", request.method, request.url))
    page.on("response", lambda response: print("<<", response.status, response.url))
    page.goto("https://example.com")
    browser.close()
```

For Example:

```
page.on("response", lambda response: response if key in response.body())
```

There should be waitForResponse for python too, and you could use that.